# python regex match and replace escaped characters with in quotes

Tags: python, regex

Given a string say

```
test = '''my name\t is "zyb\org"''';
```

I would like to match the "\o" character occuring with in the double quotes and replace it with "o". I am struggling with a suitable way to do it. Please help.

I understand how to match the double quotes using

```
 "\"(.+)\""g
```

but writing an embedded regexp to identify the escape character is where I am facing issues.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the \o character is. did you perhaps mean a different escape character?

Comment: Nope, it comes in some natural text, not meant to be a escape charater..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with:

```
".*(\\.).*"gim
```

Which does:

```
"".*(\\.).*""gim

    " matches the characters " literally
    .* matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    1st Capturing group (\\.)
        \\ matches the character \ literally
        . matches any character (except newline)
    .* matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    " matches the characters " literally
    g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
    i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
    m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

And here's the <kbd>[LiveDemo](https://regex101.com/r/sE6dF5/1)</kbd>

---

Here's a way to do it:

```
import re
line = '''my name\t is "zyb\org"'''
replaced = re.sub(r'"(.*)\\(.*)"', r"\1\2", line)
print(replaced)
```

Comment: Hey Thanks Thomas. I want to eventually replace the "\o" character in the string with "o"...

Comment: I tried p = re.compile(ur'".*(\\.).*"', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE); pattern = re.search(p,  test); result = re.sub(pattern.group(1), "o", test)